# Query in field list string Cloud Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### I need to return all documents from a collection from the tags field.

The tags field is a list of strings, I need to return all documents that the id is equal to the tagId that I send in the where parameter to query.

Below my code to make the query.

```
  document = this.afs.collection(entity || path,
    ref => ref.where(where.field, where.condition, where.value));
```

**where.field:** tags

**where.condition:** ==

**where.value:** '9fizZoFA75NjQgVkoBfD'

**You are not returning any documents the way I am doing, what can I be doing wrong?**

[image]

Comment: I'm not trying to search inside an object, I'm trying to search inside an array, inside that array I have objects with a value of type string.

Comment: This is an event that does not meet my need https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays?hl=en. In this example a query is made inside an object and not inside an array of objects with a string value.